# How to look up if an employee is on time

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, vlookup

I have the raw attendance of my team in one tab, and I created an IF statement to identify whether they are tardy or on time-based on their scheduled time (8 am PST).

- `N2` = actual log in
- `O2` = scheduled
- `=IF(N2>02,"Late","On Time")`

I created another sheet, which will basically be the dashboard. How do I look up if an employee is on time or late with their name and dates as the criteria?

Comment: This question has been bumped by Community user three times. Question like this should describe the relevant spreadsheet parts and include sample data for the formula references as well for the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

Guessing your actual layout, you may try something like this:

```
=IFNA(FILTER(Sheet1!P:P,INT(Sheet1!O:O)=A1,Sheet1!A:A=A2))
```

- Sheet1!P:P: Column that determines if tardy
- Sheet1!O:O: column of logging,. INT will let you get the day without the time
- A1: Cell where you have the date to filter
- Sheet1!A:A: column where you have the employees' names
- A2: Cell of the dashboard where you have the name to find